# How to get shutdown reason in .NET Core 3.1 Azure Web App

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, azure-webapps

Is there an equivalent to .NET Framework's *HostingEnvironment.ShutdownReason* in .NET Core 3.1? How can I get a meaningful shutdown reason for my **Azure hosted web application** PRIOR to shutdown?

I am looking for something like that:

```
// this code is called when the web app stops    
private void OnShutdown()
{
    myCustomLogger.LogAppShutdown(HostingEnvironment.ShutdownReason);
}
```

Comment: did u ever get an answer....